# From source in some instances I have 3 digit number with leading '0' and some some 2 digit number, how to build case to compare correct assignment

Tags: sql-server

I have tried to create case statement to validate source and target columns data records, however in some instances it would come with 3 digit numbers with leading zero or 2 digit number without zero. How to create case statement to give me correct results.

I have tried using code below but it assigns always 3 digit regardless

```
    COLUMN_ASSIGNMENT = (
         CASE 
          WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL
               THEN RIGHT('000'+ CAST(col1 AS VARCHAR(3)),3)
          WHEN col1 IS NULL
                THEN RIGHT('000'+ CAST(col2 AS varchar(3)),3)
          ELSE NULL
          END
           )
```

So if I receive 3 digit number with leading zero I want that to be assigned under COLUMN_ASSIGNMENT, if I receive 2 digit number it should be assigned as such under COLUMN_ASSIGNMENT

Comment: What is the "correct" output? There isn't enough context or explanation of the requirements here for others to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do the `THEN RIGHT('000'+ CAST(col1 AS VARCHAR(3)),3)` code for this. If you want the number assigned as is (that is, '022' gets assigned as '022' and '22' gets assigned as '22', then just remove the zero padding code.

Comment: For some reason COLUMN_ASSIGNMENT gets 22 if 022 is in source in other cases not